# URL Thumbnail image

Tags: html, css

How do I show thumbnail image when I share my URL?

For [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XrmN.png).

Comment: share it where?

Comment: You need to clearly explain exactly what you are trying to do, do you mean how to display a thumbnail on something like Facebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your website an image or a favicon. A favicon is the small icon you see next to the site title. To add a favicon, simply create an image, name it `favicon.ico`, and put `<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">` in the `<head>` of your website. You can generate favicons [here](https://www.favicon.cc/):

Comment: I'm confused as to how you came to the conclusion that the original question was relating to a favicon, and seemingly according to the upvotes that you were correct!? So kudos if you understood the question.

Comment: @JonB the image looks like it was taken in microsoft teams or outlook and when i tested links there it shows the favicon before any other pictures (favicons have higher priority)

Comment: Ah I see I don't use teams